# Add argument for LoginScreen()?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm trying to navigate to my login screen but I have to add argument `onClickedLogin` and I don't know how to get that to work... what can I do? I'm a little out of my depth, trying to use code from two different classes.

This is what I have:

```
onPressed: () {
                () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                          onClickedLogin: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
              },
```

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() onClickedLogin;

  const LoginScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.onClickedLogin,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Let me know if you need to see more code.

I get redirected to this page
[image: redirected to here]

Answer (score 0):

You were creating a function inside `onPressed` which you were not calling. A better way is this:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => LoginScreen(onClickedLogin: () {}),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated my question to show the page I get redirected to, not sure what it means

Comment: Do you have a material widget like a Scaffold on top of your widget? Can you share minimum reproducible code?